# Ember Link-to not rendering template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

Here are the routers and the routes of the ember project, in the template there is a link called **{{#link-to 'submit'}}** that will display the submit template within the index template.

This works fine when I type the URL on the address bar (*address#/submit*)  but this doesn't work when licking the **{{#link-to 'submit'}}Submit{{/link-to}}**.

When clicking the link the URL changes to (*adress#/submit*) but the submit template is not rendered it just shows the normal index template. No errors on the console as well. What should I change?

Thanks

```
App.Router.map(function() {    
this.resource("submit", { path: '/submit' });
});


App.SubmitRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        renderTemplate: function() {

        this.render('submit', {
            outlet : 'submit' ,
            into  : 'index'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have an `{{outlet 'submit'}}` in your index template?  You may also want to enable `LOG_TRANSITIONS: true` in your application for more debugging info.  Another recommendation is to use the Chrome Ember Inspector plugin and see what templates your view is using.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to pass in the context in the link-to helper.

{{#link-to 'submit' **this**}}Submit{{/link-to}}

Also, just some advice, Resources are associated with nouns and Routes with verbs. So I'd change your router to use this.Route("submit");
If the path is the same as the template the route will be implicitly generated.

Comment: The freaken 'this'. Not even the official docs, or any tutorial says this. http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/ seriously, WTF. I spent way too much time experimenting and searching for a basic, stupid link.

Comment: The href on such a link is '#', not the first string argument I specified.